# Schema while storing relation in PigLatin

Tags: apache-pig, store

While I store a relation in PigLatin, the data is stored and when LOAD is performed again I need to specify schema. Is there a way to store schema along with the data? I am using Pig 0.8.2

Comment: that depends. which loader are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pig: loading a data file using an external schema file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173335/pig-loading-a-data-file-using-an-external-schema-file)