# Pig: load data with .pig_schema schema file

Tags: csv, apache-pig, schema, text-files

How can I load a data file with a `.pig_schema` schema file in the same directory?

The [official Apache Pig documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173335/pig-loading-a-data-file-using-an-external-schema-file) lack any proper explanation of what the different schema fields mean or the different data type values are.

Could someone give a better, more detailed example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load data in Pig, you can optionally define its schema in a  `.pig_schema` JSON file that sits in your data directory:

```
data/
├── data_file.csv
└── .pig_schema
```

If your `data_file.csv` looks like:

```
3,0,(mybytearray),{(1.7)},[wesam#2.9]
9,8,(mybytearray),{(0.6)},[elshamy#6.5]
```

and you use this `.pig_schema` file:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "myint",
      "type": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "mylong",
      "type": 15
    },
    {
      "name": "mytupe",
      "type": 110,
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "mybytearray",
            "type": 50
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mybag",
      "type": 120,
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "mytupe",
            "type": 110,
            "schema": {
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "myfloat",
                  "type": 20
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mymap",
      "type": 100,
      "schema": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": null,
            "type": 25
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and load your data with this Pig script.

```
b = LOAD '/path/to/data' USING PigStorage(',');
```

your data will have the following schema:

```
b: {myint: int,mylong: long,mytupe: (mybytearray: bytearray),mybag: {mytupe: (myfloat: float)},mymap: map[double]}
```

In the `.pig_schema` JSON file, the value of the `"fields"` key is an array of all the fields you have in your data.  Every field is defined by a JSON object with:

- `"name"` field name (e.g: `"my_field"`).
- `"type"` integer representing the type of the field (e.g: `55`) (see type values below).
- `"schema"` [optional] defines schema for complex types (`tuple`, `bag`, `map`).

The `"type"` values for the different Pig data types are:

```
int       : 10
long      : 15
float     : 20
double    : 25
bytearray : 50
chararray : 55
map       : 100
tuple     : 110
bag       : 120
```

Comment: Not sure if it is needed, but I always see this syntax when storing or loading loading with schema: `PigStorage(',','-schema')`